# Kubernetes (GKE) persistent volume resizing not working.

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to resize the persistent volume in Google Kubernetes Engine. but I ending up with an error

> The PersistentVolumeClaim "pvc1" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: field is immutable after creation

I have been following https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/ guide.

Steps 
 1. Created a standard.yaml file with following content

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
allowVolumeExpansion: true
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```

2. Created gke-pvc.yml with following content

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc1
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: standard
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

3. Ran kubectl apply -f standard.yaml

4. Ran kubectl apply -f gke-pvc.yml
5. Now ran kubectl edit pvc pvc1 and changed storage from 20Gi to 30 Gi and saved the file but I got error

> error: persistentvolumeclaims "pvc1" is invalid
>   error: persistentvolumeclaims "pvc1" is invalid
>   A copy of your changes has been stored to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-0hztl.yaml"

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior on GKE. I believe feature is available on [Kubernetes 1.11](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/06/27/kubernetes-1.11-release-announcement/) but not yet released on [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/release-notes). If you want early access to feature, you may sign up [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdHzk8ZbhVm7NdCYU_0h88DOGNB1r9nbUMh5xrtF6YxHtSrGA/viewform).

Answer (score 0):

It is working currently, after you edit pvc, you get this message:

```
conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-02-17T23:31:42Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Resizing
```

and soon after, this:

```
    message: Waiting for user to (re-)start a pod to finish file system resize of
      volume on node.
    status: "True"
    type: FileSystemResizePending
```

Then just delete pod and your volume will be resized